# How can I save data from one site to another sites database?

Tags: php, html

How can I save data from one site to another sites database? I need to make a form which saves data to an external database. I tried using `fopen` but I don't think this is the correct way to do it:

```
$externalsave = fopen('http://onewebsite.com/folder/this_page_INSERTS_INTO_DB.php?datavalue1='.$data1.'&datavalue2='.$data2, 'r');
$data = '';
while(!feof($externalsave)) 
   $data .= fread($externalsave, 4092); 
fclose($externalsave); 

echo $data;
```

Does someone know how I can save values inserted in a form on one website, in an external database?

I'm using an Apache server, and the code above works fine, I just don't trust it. Or can I?

Comment: Are you saving from database to database? Or are you just trying to write to a remote database from another website.

Comment: [CURL](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is your best friend here.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work (or you could just use `file_get_contents` for simplicity) but external URL fetching may be disabled - some shared PHP hosts don't permit it.

Comment: Equally you could try connecting from one web server to the database server on the other - though it depends on how the firewall it set up, as it is often not permitted. (You should get into the habit of describing your server environment in your questions, so people can help you more easily - shared/dedi? OS?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 3 main solutions :

**1. Remote action**

The easiest one is to simply point your form on the remote server. For exemple :

```
<form method="post" action="http://myothersite.com/myphpscript.php">
</form>
```

And in `myphpscript.php` simply handle the form like you will in localhost.

**2. Proxy action** (require the allow_url_fopen directive to be enabled)

You could also point your form on a php script on the same server which gonna send your data on the other server.
This solution can be usefull to bypass security like csrf token :

```
<form method="post" action="proxy.php"></form>
```

proxy.php :

```
$postdata = http_build_query($_POST); //Need some filtering !!!

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://myotherserver.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

No need of curl here ;)

**3. Remote database**

Finally you can use a database with remote access and simply connect to the database  with its remote host like :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('mydbHost.com', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Unfortunately this solution is rarely allowed because it could represent a big security risk (anyone in the world can try to connect to the database).

Comment: Please take care when editing your answers - you removed some of my tweaks (would you merge them back in?).

Comment: sorry, my bad, didn't saw your edit before rewriting big part of my answer.

Comment: Got it too work, I used the second method 'Proxy action'. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simplest answer:

- Setup a form on SITE A.
- Point the form action towards a script on SITE B.
- Have SITE B validate the incoming variables and insert.

You could also use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) if you don't actually want to create a form on SITE A.

Comment: What if there is CSRF protection, like a token?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cURL, could you show an example of how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you should set mysql (I suppose your database is MySQL) to listen for network connection and connect directly to it.

on DB server comment 'bind-address = 127.0.0.1' in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and restart Mysql daemon.

on web server, do :

```
$dbconnection = mysql_connect('IP_OF_DB_SERVER', 'username', 'userpassword');
```

and simply insert your data in database.